# How can I restore git project from an old .git files and project(just have folders. server died) to bitbucket account?

Tags: git, server, bitbucket, restore

I had git project that running on my own server. But server died. I have just only project folders on my computer. I created git account on Bitbucket and created a new project. But I don't know to how to restore my old git folders(project) on my Bitbucket cloud account. Is that possible? I want to access old project history etc. Can you help me?

Comment: Ok I'll try to better understand. There are two machines named "own server" and "my computer". There was a git repository on machine "own server". "own server" is now broken. 

When "own server" was running, you were using "my computer" to push to "own server", right? So there must be a git repository on "my computer". Can you find it? You must look for folders with name ".git".

Comment: 1- I have no back up and i cant acces my broken server.
2- Yes i was using  "my computer" to push to "own server"

Yes. I know. i have .git file on my project folder

Comment: So you should be able to "git log" on your PC?

Comment: Yes i have git log

Comment: Then you have everything on your PC, nothing lost. Type "git remote add bitbucket <URL>", and use the URL Bitbucket shows when you press the "Clone" button (copy only the URL, not the git clone command). Then do a "git push bitbucket -u HEAD".

Comment: Thank you  so much Dear Marcus. Im grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a working git repository on your local machine? Can you open a git bash, cd into that folder, and `git log` and so on?

Then you can simply add the bitbucket as remote:

```
git remote add local_name_for_remote url_to_bitbucket
```

Replace "local_name_for_remote" with just anything you want - "origin" is a very commonly used local name, for example.

The URL to use is just the same you would use for cloning. Bitbucket tells the URL, simply copy-and-paste it. When ready, push your local history to bitbucket:

```
git push origin -u HEAD
```

(where `origin` is the name you choosed when adding the remote).

Comment: I had git repository running on my local server. But it died. I have got just git project files. So git "remote add local_name_for_remote url_to_bitbucket" this code is not work. I cant reach .git project clone url runing on my old local server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what you mean by "git project files" and "local server". Don't you have a clone on your local machine? What were you working with? If no clone on local machine, can you access .git folder from broken server?

Comment: Sorry my bad english Dear Marcus. Yes i have project clone on my pc.

Comment: Absolutely no problem with your english, mine is bad too. If you have a clone on your PC, everything is fine. It is a *clone*. Anything what has ever been on your server is duplicated on your PC. Just use your PC and do what I wrote in my answer. Be lucky that you use git!